# Riak's erlang pb client and map fetch

Tags: erlang, riak

I am trying to store a map of registers and sets in Riak and process them using Riak's pb client. My goal here is to save the map, then extract the persisted map from the returned object and process it (in this case extract the registers, values from sets and translate to JSON). Seems like trying to use riakc_map:fetch to extract values from the returned object is not the right way??

Here's how I am creating it (key is an uuid, QP is list of ints):

```
M = riak:new_map(),
M1 = riak:map_update({<<"post_id">>, register},
    fun(R) -> riakc_register:set(Key, R) end, M),
M2 = riak:map_update({<<"userids">>, set},
    fun(S) ->
        [riakc_set:add_element(helpers:int_to_bin(Q), S) || Q <- QP]
    end, M2),
[...]
```

I then wrap it in an object, and save the the object.

```
Obj = riakc_obj:new(<<?POST_BUCKET>>, Key, Map) %% Map created via new_map()
{ok, Obj2} = riakc_pb_socket:put(Pid, <<?POST_BUCKET>>, Obj, [return_body])
```

Now this is where I run into trouble:

```
Post = binary_to_term(riakc_obj:get_value(Obj2)));
Keys = riakc_map:fetch_keys(Post),  %% returns []
OrigMap = riakc_map:value(Post),    %% returns []
IsKey1 = riakc_map:is_key({<<"post_id">>, register}, Post), %% false
IsKey2 = riakc_map:is_key({<<"post_id">>}, Post),   %% false
```

Most importantly

```
PostId = riakc_map:fetch({<<"post_id">>, register}, Post),
```

dies with

```
{function_clause, [{orddict,fetch, ...
```

Post after *binary_to_term(riakc_obj:get_value(Obj2)));* looks correct as far as I can tell:

```
< Post = {map,[],
          [{{<<"content">>,register},
            {register,<<>>,<<"<post>Hello, World!\r\n</post>">>}},
           {{<<"post_id">>,register},
            {register,<<>>,<<"238e4300-a651-11e4-86c8-6003088f077a">>}},
           {{<<"userids">>,set},
              [{set,[],[<<"-1">>],[],undefined}]},
            .....
```

Any help greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things not quite right.  This call to update

```
M2 = riakc_map:update({<<"userids">>, set}, 
    fun(S) ->
        [riakc_set:add_element(helpers:int_to_bin(Q), S) || Q <- QP]
    end, M1),
```

does not create a set with several members, it creates a list of sets each with a single member.  If you are trying to construct a set of integers, use a fold instead of a list comprehension:

```
M2 = riakc_map:update({<<"userids">>, set}, 
    fun(S) ->
        lists:foldl(
               fun(Q, Acc) ->
                   riakc_set:add_element(helpers:int_to_bin(Q), Acc) 
               end, 
               S, QP),
    end, M1),
```

This doesn't actually update the value of the map, it stages updates in the record:

```
#map{value = [],
     updates = [{{<<"post_id">>,register},
                 {register,<<>>,<<"uuid">>}},
                {{<<"userids">>,set},
                 {set,[],
                      [<<"1">>,<<"10">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"5">>,<<"6">>,
                       <<"7">>,<<"8">>,<<"9">>],
                      [],undefined}}],
     removes = [],context = undefined}
```

At this point, `riakc_map:value` returns `[]` because that is the value in the record.  To apply the staged updates to the value, you would need to call `riakc_pb_socket:modify_type` which would also store the value in Riak.

---

### The full process

#### Prepare the Riak cluster to use the map CRDT

- Create a bucket type to hold a map
  `root@node# riak-admin bucket-type create maps '{"props":{"datatype":"map"}}'`
- Activate the bucket type
  `root@node# riak-admin bucket-type activate maps`

#### Create map and update Riak

```
1> rr(riakc_map).
[map]
2> {ok,Pid}=riakc_pb_socket:start("127.0.0.1",8087),
2> M=riakc_map:new(),
2> Key = <<"testkey">>,
2> Bucket = <<"testbucket">>,
2> Type = <<"maps">>,
2> QP = lists:seq(1,10),
2> M1 = riakc_map:update({<<"post_id">>, register},
2> fun(R) -> riakc_register:set(Key, R) end, M),
2> M2 = riakc_map:update({<<"userids">>, set},
2> fun(S) ->
2> lists:foldl(fun(Q,Acc) -> riakc_set:add_element(list_to_binary(integer_to_list(Q)), Acc) end,S, QP)
2> end, M1),
2> riakc_pb_socket:modify_type(Pid,fun(_) -> M2 end,{Type,Bucket},Key,[create]).
ok
```

#### Retrieve the map and check values

```
3> {ok,Map} = riakc_pb_socket:fetch_type(Pid,{Type,Bucket},Key),
3> riakc_map:value(Map).
[{{<<"post_id">>,register},<<"testkey">>},
 {{<<"userids">>,set},
  [<<"1">>,<<"10">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"5">>,<<"6">>,
   <<"7">>,<<"8">>,<<"9">>]}]
4> riakc_map:fetch_keys(Map).
[{<<"post_id">>,register},{<<"userids">>,set}]
5> riakc_map:is_key({<<"post_id">>, register}, Map).
true
6> riakc_map:is_key({<<"post_id">>}, Map).
false
```

For comparison, this is the value before it was stored:

```
7> M2.

#map{value = [],
     updates = [{{<<"post_id">>,register},
                 {register,<<>>,<<"testkey">>}},
                {{<<"userids">>,set},
                 {set,[],
                      [<<"1">>,<<"10">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"5">>,<<"6">>,
                       <<"7">>,<<"8">>,<<"9">>],
                      [],undefined}}],
     removes = [],context = undefined}
```

And this is the final value:

```
8> Map.
#map{value = [{{<<"post_id">>,register},<<"testkey">>},
              {{<<"userids">>,set},
               [<<"1">>,<<"10">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"5">>,<<"6">>,
                <<"7">>,<<"8">>,<<"9">>]}],
     updates = [],removes = [],
     context = <<131,108,0,0,0,1,104,2,109,0,0,0,8,35,9,254,
                 249,120,246,57,114,97,8,106>>}
```

Changing an existing map is handled with an implicit fetch:

```
2> riakc_pb_socket:modify_type(Pid,
                 fun(OldMap) ->
                    riakc_map:update({<<"userids">>, set},
                               fun(S) ->
                                   riakc_set:add_element(<<"100">>, S)
                               end, OldMap)
                 end,
                 {Type,Bucket},Key,[]).
ok
3> riakc_pb_socket:fetch_type(Pid,{Type,Bucket},Key).
{ok,{map,[{{<<"post_id">>,register},<<"testkey">>},
      {{<<"userids">>,set},
       [<<"1">>,<<"10">>,<<"100">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"5">>,
        <<"6">>,<<"7">>,<<"8">>,<<"9">>]}],
     [],[],
     <<131,108,0,0,0,1,104,2,109,0,0,0,8,35,9,254,249,120,
       246,57,114,97,...>>}}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this with so much detail. And also, thanks for correcting the list comprehension issue. I am planning on using update_type() for creation to avoid doing the unnecessary fetch which modify_type() will do regardless of passing in create as an option (https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client/blob/master/src/riakc_pb_socket.erl#L1197-L1199). I was, in error, mixing in older ways of accessing the data with the new ways of dealing with CRDTs.